# Python - Convert a list from a text file containing IP's addresses and dissimilar data, to CSV

Tags: python, regex, list, csv, ip-address

I've been tasked with creating a list of NFS shares and associated IP's from several text files and save it as CSV.  The file contains NFS share names and IP's along with other data I don't wish to include in the CSV

text file example:

> /vol/vm-01
>   -sec=sys,rw=10.44.160.133:10.44.160.132:10.44.160.131:10.44.160.130,root=10.44.160.133:10.44.160.132:10.44.160.131:10.44.160.130 /vol/vol01
>   -sec=sys,rw=10.44.202.39:10.44.202.73,root=10.44.202.39:10.44.202.73

I've used regex and filtered out the IP's easily enough but can't find a way to merge the volume name in.

```
# Scrape file for IP's using RegEx
with open('input.txt') as f:
    qlist = [re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', i ) for i in f.readlines()]
    for x in range(len(qlist)):
        print(qlist[x])
```

Example Output:

> ['10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131', '10.44.160.130',
>   '10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131', '10.44.160.130']
>   ['10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73', '10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73']

Desired Output:

> ['vm-01', '10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131',
>   '10.44.160.130', '10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131',
>   '10.44.160.130'] ['vol01', '10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73',
>   '10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
import re

qlist = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        tmp = []
        # search the volume name
        m = re.search(r'/vol/(\S+)', line)
        tmp.append(m.group(1))
        # loop on all IPs
        for i in re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line ):
            tmp.append(i)
        qlist.append(tmp)
for x in range(len(qlist)):
    print(qlist[x])
```

**Output:**

```
['vm-01', '10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131', '10.44.160.130', '10.44.160.133', '10.44.160.132', '10.44.160.131', '10.44.160.130']
['vol01', '10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73', '10.44.202.39', '10.44.202.73']
```

Comment: I ran this on multiple files and it's working as advertised.  I didn't anticipate dealing with the duplicates and would make a good addition.  Any advice?

Comment: @Thurber: Are you talking about IPs? In that case, just test if value exists before `append` something like `if i in tmp break`

Answer (score 0):

This expression does return both desired outputs, and you can likely and simply script the rest so that to get the final output:

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+?)(?=\s+-sec)"
test_str = "/vol/vm-01 -sec=sys,rw=10.44.160.133:10.44.160.132:10.44.160.131:10.44.160.130,root=10.44.160.133:10.44.160.132:10.44.160.131:10.44.160.130 /vol/vol01 -sec=sys,rw=10.44.202.39:10.44.202.73,root=10.44.202.39:10.44.202.73"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

> [('', 'vm-01'), ('10.44.160.133', ''), ('10.44.160.132', ''),
>   ('10.44.160.131', ''), ('10.44.160.130', ''), ('10.44.160.133', ''),
>   ('10.44.160.132', ''), ('10.44.160.131', ''), ('10.44.160.130', ''),
>   ('', 'vol01'), ('10.44.202.39', ''), ('10.44.202.73', ''),
>   ('10.44.202.39', ''), ('10.44.202.73', '')]

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mrNRe5/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mrNRe5/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: I used the Regex statement you provided with the following code and in doing so, was able to modify the statement to output a list for each line in the file and associate the volume.  I've been working on some clean-up to remove the unwanted characters "() ' '' for example.  It is however; working.